# The One Above All - Will We Ever See Again?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars

As every cosmic entity fell to the Beyonders during the events leading up to Secret Wars, this begs the question, where was the One Above All during all this?  I assumed that the destruction of the multiverse might stir him out for a page or two somewhere during the story arc, but no.

I was wondering why the One Above All was NOT included in Hickman's run of all these great comics, considering the scope and size of the event.  And, since we haven't seen him, when do comic fans expect that another visit may come?

Comment: As his name suggests, he was above it all.

Comment: So you don't think that the aforementioned person took his place...but he is creating universes!  Wouldn't the One Above All have that job?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because irt conflicts with our "future works" policy; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/should-we-add-an-off-topic-close-reason-for-future-works

Comment: One Above All is an avatar for the author.  So I'd say he was busy having the Beyonders destroy the multiverse in order to make an epic story.