# Is There a New One Above All?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars

[In this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114829/the-one-above-all-we-we-ever-see-again) I made, I was wondering about the whereabouts of the One Above All in the Marvel Universe.  Considering the events of Time Runs Out and Secret Wars, I have to wonder, since the Beyonders are from essentially outside the Multiverse, and they seem to be destroying everything in the multiverse, since they have the ability to destroy the Multiverse,

> did they kill or usurp the One Above All?

Then at the conclusion of Secret Wars,

> Franklin Richards is seen creating the universe as he sees fit as the current All New All Different Marvel universe is essentially the same Universe pre Secret Wars with some changes being employed such as the inclusion of Miles Morales.

So does this imply that he is the new One Above All?  I don't know if there is a canonical answer to this question since no comics have been written that can confirm any of this, but it seems plausible..

Answer (score 3):

I can find no reference made to The One-Above-All when the Beyonders come to destroy the Multiverse. The [Beyonders](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Beyonders) themselves come from outside the Multiverse, and slay the Celestials, Eternity, Infinity, Lord Chaos, Master Order, the In-Betweener, and finally the Living Tribunal. However, crucially, they do not come in to contact with the One-Above-All, the only entity to whom the [Living Tribunal](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal_(Multiverse)) is subordinate.

The [One-Above-All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One-Above-All_(Multiverse)) is 'apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the Multiverse and possibly beyond'. An attempt by [The Protege](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Protege_(Earth-691)) to usurp the One-Above-All - having outmatched the Living Tribunal - failed and she was ultimately absorbed by the Living Tribunal.

Therefore I would tentatively conclude that:

- The One-Above-All remained aloof from the conflict between the Beyonders and the Multiverse
- The One-Above-All is likely to also be the author and sustainer of life beyond the Multiverse, such as the Beyonders
- Franklin Richards did not become the new One-Above-All.

Furthermore, in a far (possible) future, the One-Below-All (the dark side and a part of the same being known as the One-Above-All) successfully [*killed* Franklin Richards](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Below_All_(Multiverse)), indicating that Franklin is not and was never the One-Above-All.

Answer (score 2):

Well . . . depending on how one views it, the "One Above All" will be at NY Comicon in a few weeks.  Often, the term is used within the Marvel Universe to depict either Stan Lee or Jack Kirby.

Answer (score 0):

The one above all is essentially the embodiment of whoever is writing the comic book, and is the God of the marvel Megaverse, usually unaffected by events in any one Multiverse. As long as the events that happen are within the Marvel Megaverse ( which they are unless it is a crossover with, say, DC ) he still controls everything that happens.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite answers the question of whether the identity of the One Above All changed during Secret Wars.

Comment: You seem to be posting quite a lot of 'stub' answers; terse and offering only your opinion without backing it up with any evidence. This is (inevitably) going to lead to your answers being downvote and deleted. Instead of posting lots of *low quality* answers, why not have a look at some of the [top-voted answers in this category](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20%5bcomics%5d) and have a go at writing something more tangible?

Comment: That’s not true.

Comment: Which part isn't true?

Comment: All of that comment. There is evidence in the answer.